# How to open property page on click of custom menu item in Eclipse RCP using custom plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to open a properties page on the click of my custom menu item entry using my new plugin. What all things do i need to add to
my plugins.xml

This plugin.xml does not produce the desired result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.2"?>
<plugin>
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages">
   <page
        class="com.abc.gis.map.displayscale.DisplayPropertiesSummary"
        id="com.abc.gis.map.displayScale.page3"
        name="Test"
        objectClass="net.refractions.udig.project.IMap">
  </page>
  </extension>

   <extension
          point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
    <handler
          class="com.abc.gis.map.displayscale.DisplayPropertiesCommandHandler"
          commandId="com.abc.gis.map.displayscale.displayProperties">
       <enabledWhen>
          <iterate
                ifEmpty="false"
                operator="or">
             <adapt
                   type="net.refractions.udig.project.IMap">
             </adapt>
             <instanceof
                   value="net.refractions.udig.project.IMap">
             </instanceof>
          </iterate>
       </enabledWhen>
    </handler>
    </extension>

 </plugin>
```

I am trying to open a simple properties page that will contain my user input tools like radio buttons in this properties page. This properties page shall open up on the click of my custom menu item.

[image: Custom Menu Item]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `createPropertyDialogOn` methods of `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PreferencesUtil` to show a particular property page. Something like:

```
PreferencesUtil.createPropertyDialogOn(getShell(), obj, id, new String[] {id}, input).open()
```